# Software to switch between IP settings

Tags: windows, gratis, networking

Whenever you are travelling, connecting to test networks or similar, you have to toggle between DHCP and static IPs, turn proxies on and off, change routes etc.

It was just a matter of time until I needed a program like [NetSetMan](http://www.netsetman.com) (Network Settings Manager) again. Unfortunately our company doesn't have a license and the free version does not allow commercial use.

Therefore I'm looking for a free alternative that at least allows

- defining 5 or more profiles
- supports static IPs and DHCP
- supports switching the DNS server
- supports setting up a proxy
- supports setting up routes (ideally but optional for now, since I don't need this feature urgently)
- is gratis
- works on Windows

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Free IP Switcher](http://www.eusing.com/ipswitch/free_ip_switcher.htm).

It meets the requirements like this:

- allows defining 5 configurations ("sets") by default. More can be added. The sets can be renamed.

  [image: Sets]
- supports static IPs and DHCP

  [image: IP and DHCP]
- supports switching the DNS server

  [image: DNS server]
- supports setting up a proxy

  [image: Proxy]
- is gratis. It asks for registration, but this step can be skipped.
- works on Windows 2000/XP/2003/Vista/7/8 officially

It does not support changing routes and you can't change multiple adapters in one set.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to your answer, there is another tool: [Simple IP Config](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simpleipconfig/)

> Description
>
> Simple IP Config is a small ip changer utility to change common
>   Windows network settings quickly and easily. This includes IP Address,
>   Subnet Mask, Gateway, and DNS Server.

Features

- View / Change IP Address, Subnet Mask, Gateway, DNS Server
- Simple, easy to use interface
- Small size - less than 1MB download!
- No install necessary - even run from USB
- Enable / Disable Network Adapters
- **Save unlimited number of profiles for quickly changing settings**
- Free

[image]

*Note: Image for illustration purposes only. Version 2.7 available from authour's website(Last Update: 2017-04-22)*